# I can't understand the following Errors on my Unfolding Maps Project

Tags: java, unfoldingmap

I'm trying to display the data of earthquakes from the entire world using Unfolding Maps but I stuck the error which I don't understand. Please Help me by resolving these errors

In the past, I have tried to run the Maps offline by setting the boolean value to true but I didn't work.

The Problem is from Coursera and in the form of assignment. I'm getting troubleshoot in this assignment

```
Using OpenGLMapDisplay with processing.opengl.PGraphics3D
Exception in thread "Animation Thread" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at module3.EarthquakeCityMap.setup(EarthquakeCityMap.java:102)
    at processing.core.PApplet.handleDraw(PApplet.java:2365)
    at processing.opengl.PJOGL$PGLListener.display(PJOGL.java:873)
    at jogamp.opengl.GLDrawableHelper.displayImpl(GLDrawableHelper.java:690)
    at jogamp.opengl.GLDrawableHelper.display(GLDrawableHelper.java:672)
    at javax.media.opengl.awt.GLCanvas$10.run(GLCanvas.java:1383)
    at jogamp.opengl.GLDrawableHelper.invokeGLImpl(GLDrawableHelper.java:1277)
    at jogamp.opengl.GLDrawableHelper.invokeGL(GLDrawableHelper.java:1131)
    at javax.media.opengl.awt.GLCanvas$11.run(GLCanvas.java:1394)
    at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(InvocationEvent.java:301)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:758)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(EventQueue.java:97)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:709)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:703)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:74)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:728)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:205)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:116)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:93)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:82)
```

```
 List<Marker> markers = new ArrayList<Marker>();

    //Use provided parser to collect properties for each earthquake
    //PointFeatures have a getLocation method
    List<PointFeature> earthquakes = ParseFeed.parseEarthquake(this, earthquakesURL);

    for (PointFeature eq: earthquakes) {
        markers.add(new SimplePointMarker(eq.getLocation(), eq.getProperties()));
    }

    // Add the markers to the map so that they are displayed
    map.addMarkers(markers);



int yellow = color(255,255,0);
int gray = color(150,150,150);

for(Marker mk : markers) {
    if ((int) mk.getProperty("year") > 2000) {
        mk.setColor(yellow);
    }
    else {
        mk.setColor(gray);
    }
}


}


@SuppressWarnings("unused")
private SimplePointMarker createMarker(PointFeature feature)
{  
    // To print all of the features in a PointFeature (so you can see what they are)
    // uncomment the line below.  Note this will only print if you call createMarker 
    // from setup
    //System.out.println(feature.getProperties());

    // Create a new SimplePointMarker at the location given by the PointFeature
    SimplePointMarker marker = new SimplePointMarker(feature.getLocation());

    Object magObj = feature.getProperty("magnitude");
    float mag = Float.parseFloat(magObj.toString());

    // Here is an example of how to use Processing's color method to generate 
    // an int that represents the color yellow.  
    int yellow = color(255, 255, 0);


    // Finally return the marker
    return marker;
}

public void draw() {
    background(10);
    map.draw();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This the exception

```
Exception in thread "Animation Thread" java.lang.NullPointerException
```

This is where

```
at module3.EarthquakeCityMap.setup(EarthquakeCityMap.java:102)
```

So you'll need to go into "EarthquakeCityMap.java", line 102 and find what could cause a Null Pointer Exception

Comment: Dear Brandon, this is the line 102

Comment: for(Marker mk : markers) {
    if ((int) mk.getProperty("year") > 2000) {
        mk.setColor(yellow);
    }
    else {
        mk.setColor(gray);
    }
}

Comment: but I'm the beginner to this And I don't know what type of arguments it accepts and returns

Comment: Okay, so if we're traversing a list, we need to make sure its not null (if(markers != null), as well as the result of mk.getProperty("year"), we also need to make sure isn't null before casting it to an int (as well as check that it can be casted to an int) ( if(mk.getProperty("year") != null && mk.getProperty("year") instanceOf int)

Comment: Thanks, Brandon for helping me out now the errors have been resolved.

Comment: If this is what resolved the issue please mark it as the answer or if it was something different please post your answer to the question and mark as answered